# How to interpret a model summary in a correct way, matching the conditional effects plot?

Tags: regression, modeling, interpretation

I have nine study years. Conditional effects plot of my model shows a clear effect of **year** on **Y-variable**.

**Plot**

[image]

However, how can I extract mean Y change per study year from model summary, including CIs? As this is lognormal model, I tried exp(0.05) = 1.05 increase per study year, resulting a total of 1.05*9 = 9.45 units of increase! This does not match the plot above. What am I doing wrong?

**Model summary**

hu - is for hurdle (zero inflated) part, please neglect these rows.

```
 Family: hurdle_lognormal 
  Links: mu = identity; sigma = identity; hu = logit 
Formula: Y ~ year + (1 | county) 
         hu ~ year + (1 | county)
   Data: dataformodels (Number of observations: 8649) 
Samples: 3 chains, each with iter = 2000; warmup = 1000; thin = 1;
         total post-warmup samples = 3000

Group-Level Effects: 
~county (Number of levels: 15) 
                 Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sd(Intercept)        0.38      0.08     0.25     0.57 1.00      623     1206
sd(hu_Intercept)     0.79      0.16     0.55     1.18 1.01      596     1376

Population-Level Effects: 
             Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
Intercept      -93.45     11.48  -116.20   -70.96 1.00     3230     2139
hu_Intercept   257.21     18.53   220.76   293.16 1.00     2798     2188
year             0.05      0.01     0.04     0.06 1.00     3232     2086
hu_year         -0.13      0.01    -0.15    -0.11 1.00     2800     2307

Family Specific Parameters: 
      Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS Tail_ESS
sigma     0.86      0.01     0.84     0.88 1.00     2492     2065

Samples were drawn using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```